# If you have an IBOutlet, but not a property, is it retained or not?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, interface-builder, nib

I find the documentation on this issue to be unclear:

Say you are working with iOS (NOT the Mac case, no need to mention the differences). Say it is strictly 4.0+ (no need to mention differences in old OS). Say we are loading the NIB strictly automatically.

Say you have a UIViewController, BigView. Say there are a dozen so-called "top-level" items in the NIB file...could be custom controls, images, or anything else.

Say you are definitely going to explicitly create and then get rid of BigView a number of times during the app's run.  So:

For one of these top-level items in the NIB, there are **three possibilities**:

(1) You do not have any sort of IBOutlet for it, at all.

(2) You do have a connected IBOutlet - but not a property.

(3) You do have a connected IBOutlet property (to avoid confusion, we'll say a retain property).

So what happens to the item when BigView is released?

**In the case of (3)** it seems clear that you must release explicitly.  If you do not, it will hang around after the view is gone.  No problem.

**In the case of (1)** I assume (**but can anyone actually confirm?**) that the item will be released when BigView is gone.

**In the case of (2)** it's not clear what happens.......

Looking at the well-known reference link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html it is very dubious:

> "In iOS, the nib-loading code uses the setValue:forKey: method to reconnect each outlet. That method similarly looks for an appropriate accessor method and [SO WHAT HAPPENS IF THERE ISN'T ONE?? TELL US APPLE...] falls back on other means when that fails...[GOOD GRIEF!]"

And scroll down to "Nib Object Retention":

> **"Objects in the nib file are created with a retain count of 1 and then autoreleased"** Fantastic..

But wait!  Read on a few words...

> **however, ... which uses the available setter method or retains the object by default if no setter method is available**

What are they talking about?

Do they mean that if no setter is available (ivar, but no property), that it is **AGAIN** RETAINED (other than the "retain" they just mention in the previous clause) --- or, are they just repeating themselves, i.e. the "retains the object by default" is the same "retain" they were talking about immediately previously ("created with a retain count of 1 and then autoreleased").

And why would they even mention the autorelease if that's not what happens?

Indeed -- if anyone actually specifically knows the answer to this question ...... **how do you know?!?** Did you ask DTS, or through testing, or?  I suggest, the key documentation (just pasted in) is aggressively unclear.

Again - if you have an IBOutlet, **but not a property**, connected to a "top-level" object .. **are you responsible for releasing it? Is it retained?** in that situation?

For that matter .... merely in situation (1) is it absolutely the case that the thingy will be released when BigView goes away?  I would certainly assume this is the case, but who knows?

The question is what happens if you DO use an IBOutlet iVar, but NOT a property...

I've foolishly never thought about this before / assumed too much, does anyone have the decisive answer?  Cheers!!

---

For the record I have made a test project.

In fact (surprisingly to me) **the mere act of connecting an IB element to an IBOutlet in fact apparently adds one retain**.

(I can only assume from the shoddy docu, in that situation you get specifically: Retain, Autorelease, Retain - leading to one retain on balance.)

So, that's the answer.

I will post the demo project. I also direct any readers to Jonah's answer below which flawlessly explains the behavior of setValue:forKey:   Cheers

Comment: thank you very much. i was wondering EXACTLY the same questions! i was so confused after reading apple docs so i was completely unsure what to believe in. And also thanks to Jonah for this clarification.

Comment: It's a weird one huh - I agree with you. THanks for the up-vote as that one gave me "super-being power" or something on this site!!!  I'm the king of the world !!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see what causes so much confusion, I think the "Nib Object Retention" documentation explains exactly what happens. Let's break it down and walk through what happens:

> Objects in the nib file are created with a retain count of 1 and then autoreleased.

```
ClassLoadedFromNib *loadedObject = [[[ClassLoadedFromNib alloc] initWithCoder:coder] autorelease];
```

---

> As it rebuilds the object hierarchy, however, UIKit reestablishes connections between the objects using the setValue:forKey: method,

```
[filesOwner setValue:loadedObject forKey:nameOfIBOutlet];
```

---

> which uses the available setter method or retains the object by default if no setter method is available.

The default behavior of `-setValue:forKey:` in iOS is roughly

```
//lazy pseudocode
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(@"setKeyName:")]) {
  [self setKeyName:value];
}
else {
  object_setIvar(self, _keyName, [value retain]);
}
```

See the key-value programming guide for even more detail. Unless your file's owner object overrides `-setValue:forKey:` (or `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` and `-setValue:forUndefinedKey:` ) expect object ownership to be managed as above.

---

> If you define outlets for nib-file objects, you should always define a setter method (or declared property) for accessing that outlet. Setter methods for outlets should retain their values, and setter methods for outlets containing top-level objects must retain their values to prevent them from being deallocated.

Allowing nib loading to set ivar directly to externally retained objects is confusing. Don't do that. Provide setter methods for your outlets so the ownership of the loaded object is clear.

---

> If you do not store the top-level objects in outlets, you must retain either the array returned by the loadNibNamed:owner:options: method or the objects inside the array to prevent those objects from being released prematurely.

Objects not connected to outlets have been autoreleased. Retain them or the array returned from -loadNibNamed:owner:options: if you are going to try to access them later.

Comment: Hey Joneh -- in short, that is a magnificent explanation of setValue:forKey: behavior, thank you.  (The doco. is badly flawed as I describe at length...without you we'd be stuffed.)  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting question, but because the documentation is ambiguous I think the best plan (and the one that I believe is recommended by Apple) is to make all your outlets retain properties. You know exactly what happens in that case, and there's little reason to do anything else.

Comment: I didn't dv, but surely you only need to make something an outlet if IB needs to see it and only a property if you want getters/setters?

Comment: If you need an outlet, it's because you plan on keeping a reference to something created from a nib file. Using a property to manage that reference avoids the kinds of questions raised above, and also makes memory management easier. Sure, you could use an ivar directly, but that's true of any property. Maybe you mean that you might only use a property when you intend for objects other than self to change the related value, but that's exactly what happens when you load objects from a nib.

Comment: @Joe Blow, I do think it's an interesting question, but since topics like this one tend to confuse beginners I wanted to put the best practical solution out there. I know that what I posted isn't the answer you were looking for, and if someone votes this answer down for that reason that's fine.

Comment: Do you really get a performance increase by using properties? I was under the impression that it gave you a getter and setter for that variable... I never use a property unless I have too and I've never noticed anything different in performance (although I may be wrong). EDIT: Oh wait, do you mean performance as in not to use a property to gain a slightly faster performance? If so, I understand that!! And I also do that!

Comment: @Joe yes we're on the same page here... From my experience I only use properties when I need them because a) I was always taught to create getters and setters when needed and b) I can't be arsed doing it for every var!

Answer (score 0):

Case 1) If object isn't retained by anything it will be deallocated upon next autorelease pool drain.

Case 2) In answer you mentioned above Jon Hess has already described (with a reference to documentation) differences between Mac OS X and iOS for this case.

> Jon Hess correct or is Freeman correct?

In iOS case both Hess and Freeman say that object will be retained. There is no contradiction between them on this.

It is still highly recommended to have setter methods for all outlets:

[Resource Programming Guide, Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

> If you define outlets for nib-file
>   objects, you should always define a
>   setter method (or declared property)
>   for accessing that outlet. Setter
>   methods for outlets should retain
>   their values...

Comment: Yes, it's retained and you should release it when you're done with it (in `dealloc` usually). Actually I used this approach in past but now I use properties for this because it's less confusing for future maintainers of my code.

Comment: Hi Hoha. Thank you for your guidance. In fact I made a test project and it proves the situation. I will post it. I was very surprised that the mere act of connecting an IB element to an IBOutlet in fact adds one retain. Thanks again and cheers! Sorry some idiot voted your comment down!