# Xcode - How IBOutlets and Nib files work?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib

I'm for the first time using nib files. I mean xib and the corresponding swift class.

Here is my swift class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class LittleVideoView: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    var nibName: String = "LittleVideoView"

    // MARK: Views
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var clicksLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

From the editor view I created some IBOutlets as you can see. Everything works properly.

There is just something I don't understand. I am programmatically loading the nib in this class, so why can I create IBOutlets while Xcode doesn't really knows that I will really load the correct nib file? Shortly, I don't understand how IBOutlets can work in this case. So, how will Xcode correclty link the loaded UIView in the setup() method with the IBOutlets ?

Comment: This is not an unreasonable thing to want to know, but there is no need to ask it _again_; it has been explained many times here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nib files have a "File's Owner" type which the editor uses to list available outlets and actions. However when the nib is loaded at runtime that type is not enforced. Outlet's are connected using `-setValue:forKey:` under the assumption that the "Owner" passed to `instantiateWithOwner` is compatible with any outlet bindings defined in the nib.

[One xib File with Multiple "File's Owner"s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849330/one-xib-file-with-multiple-files-owners/5850909#5850909)

[If you have an IBOutlet, but not a property, is it retained or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523290/if-you-have-an-iboutlet-but-not-a-property-is-it-retained-or-not/5525478#5525478)

Comment: Thank you, I forget about the "instantiateWithOwner" :)